# Template resolution with template template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to implement a "decoder" which can treat input data differently depending on the expected return type.

The following code seemed to work in https://cppinsights.io/:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

template<template <class, class> class V, typename T>
void Bar(V<T, std::allocator<T>> &v, char** c) {
    size_t s = *(size_t*)*c;
    v.resize(s);
    memcpy((char*)&v[0], *c, s * sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
inline void Bar(T &t, char** c) {
    t = *(T*)*c;
}

template<typename T>
T Foo(char** c) {
    T t;
    Bar<T>(t, c);
    return t;
}

char bob[] = {8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0};
char boz[] = {5,0,0,0};

int baz = Foo<int>((char **)&boz);
std::vector<int> bub = Foo<std::vector<int>>((char **)&bob);
```

So I thought that the final call to `Foo` would use the first definition of `Bar` but this is not happening, if I delete the second definition of `Bar`, the following code does not compile:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

template<template <class, class> class V, typename T>
void Bar(V<T, std::allocator<T>> &v, char** c) {
    size_t s = *(size_t*)*c;
    v.resize(s);
    memcpy((char*)&v[0], *c, s * sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
T Foo(char** c) {
    T t;
    Bar<T>(t, c);
    return t;
}

char bob[] = {8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0};

std::vector<int> bub = Foo<std::vector<int>>((char **)&bob);
```

and I get the following error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Bar' 
template<typename T> T Foo(char** c) { T t; Bar<T>(t, c); return t; }
                                            ^~~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Foo<std::vector<int>>' requested here
std::vector<int> bub = Foo<std::vector<int>>((char **)&bob);
                       ^
note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'V'
template<template <class, class> class V, typename T> void Bar(V<T, std::allocator<T>> &v, char** c) {
                                                           ^
```

I can't really understand what it means, why is the compiler not using the definition with the "template template" parameter? I have similar functions for "encoding" the data and it works, what am I doing wrong?

Am I trying to solve the wrong problem? How can I "split" the decoding function depending on the expected return type, while keeping it generic (or at least have a different handling of vector vs non-vector types)? Thanks.

Comment: rather than describing what has to be modified on the posted code to produce the error you should post the code that does produce the error, ie a [mcve]

Comment: This is not even funny anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is inside `Foo`. You're calling `Bar<T>` which is explicitly saying use the `Bar` that takes a single template argument. IE, you're making sure the `template template` specialization never gets selected. Instead, let it auto-deduce.

This worked for me: https://godbolt.org/z/14h1fdTMT

```
template<typename T>
T Foo(char** c) {
    T t;
    Bar(t, c); // auto-deduce here
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I think I will just use enable_if, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to pass `T`, which is a concrete type, in `Foo()` when you write `Bar<T>(...)`. Instead, you'd need a `template<class, class> class V` there, i.e., a class *template* with two type arguments.

Comment: I want to call a single function Foo, and then allocate an object to be 'filled' by another function Bar, depending on whether it's a scalar value or a vector. My approach might be wrong, but I can't understand why the compiler can't detect the right template to instantiate.